# How do I empty a room?

Tags: game-maker

I have a scrolling room in my game, and I want to duplicate it so I do not have to go back into the views tab again and edit each new room. Is there a way to remove all of the objects in a room at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third icon in the room editor. Select `object` tab and press the icon - all objects will be deleted. Select 'tiles' tab and press the icon - all tiles in the current layer will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

in room editor click object and press delete button